# How to toggle the visibility of multiple layers at once in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I am currently working with an .ai file which has many many layers.

I would be taking the same file to after effects later. I don't need to transport all those layers to AE.

As I am moving through the layers in Layers panel in AI, I am selecting Layers for which I need to toggle the visibility off.

I was wondering is it possible to toggle the visibility off for multiple selected layers at once in AI?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Put them in a second layer and toggle the visibility of that layer

Comment: I have inherited an artwork that has 1674 layers. Your idea would work if the ai file has less number of layers. But not with that many layers.

Comment: i doubt there are that many layers, what you see in layers panel are both layers and objects. They are not the same thing, its just that the panel is for historical reason misnamed. This  by the way a really importand detail

Comment: THe other alternatives is to load selections and toggle those or use a script. Neither of which is less work than making a new top level layer and arrange stuff you need into those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you by "selecting Layers" mean *highlighting* them in the Layers panel, you can just go to the sandwich menu, select *Options for Selection* and untick  *Show*. This also works for objects.

[image]

This doesn't work with so-called *Selected Art* with the blue square indicator to the right in the Layers panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can also select an *eye* icon and drag your mouse up/down to quickly show/hide multiple objects. Just click down, then keep your mouse button down and drag across the objects you want to toggle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a multi-layer visibility toggle. At least not one which is easy to access and doesn't require multiple clicks (in which case, it may be of no help). One could script it... or structure layers in a manner that makes it a matter of merely toggling a single layer or two rather than a large layer stack.

Hide others may help though...

- Select what you *want visible* on the artboard(s).
- Hit <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> -- this will hide everything *not* selected.
- Then the standard <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to show everything again.
- Repeat.